# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Make a batch file that will run Notepad on StartUp

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2012, notepad

I have the following question:

In Windows Server 2012 R2, how to make a batch file that will run Notepad on StartUp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that in command prompt?

Comment: Maybe it would be useful for other users.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear. The above command adds Notepad to the standard run key for the current user. As such it will only be ran on login of that particular user. If someone else logs in, it won't start automatically. This key can also be suppressed by GPO.

Comment: @Seth, Could you show the method (code) such that it will work also for multiple users?

Comment: You could try the HKLM location or setup a task. [This documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx#) has a bit more information about that Run key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure startup programs from command prompt or batch file, one can add registry setting in the following registry path. The registry paths are:

- For all user: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- For current user: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Use `reg add` command to add that registry. The path of executable file (here Notepad.exe) is: `C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe`. To set this startup *for all user*, replace `HKCU` with `HKLM`. Replace `C:\` with the system drive letter in your computer.

- The command is:

  ```
  reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "Notepad" /D "C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe" /F
  ```
- To revert/undo this startup program delete the registry with this command:

  ```
  reg delete  "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "Notepad" /F
  ```

### Further Reading:

- [MSDN: Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Tip: Understand and Control Startup Apps with the System Configuration Utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851671.aspx)
- [Technet: Reg command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490984.aspx)